# Using Keycloak in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, keycloak, keycloak-services

It appears that Keycloak does not properly work as a service in GitLab CI.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/273753

It also appears that someone has found some sort of workaround.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942345/5476186

But I'm wondering if there are other possible solutions. For instance, I've got keycloak and my app already dockerized in a `docker-compose.yml`, is there any reason I shouldn't just run `docker-compose` in my CI?